# Oracle - Toad does not recognize the tns

Tags: oracle, macos

Here is my tnsnames.ora file, when I try to connect using "Net Service name" in toad it does not recognize DR1P_ADHOC.
Nothing gets listed as the service name. I have attached a screen shot of it.

Also, this is in MAC/TOAD.

[image]

```
DR1P_ADHOC =
  (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = p07-t-ap-gid.sys.bt.net)(PORT = 1540))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = v1p_adoc1.ss.bst.net)
      (FAILOVER_MODE =
        (TYPE = SELECT)
        (METHOD = BASIC)
        (RETRIES = 180)
        (DELAY = 5)
      )
    )
  )
```

Comment: why service name is ':wq'

Comment: Also try on your console `tnsping DR1P_ADHOC` and see if it respond

Comment: @Dere0405: its a typo , i corrected it

Comment: @JorgeCampos: I'm on mac not sure how to get tnsping installed

Comment: Did you Install oracle client?

Comment: Yes, I did but I dont see a bin folder, which one should I install, there are many items listed

Comment: The problem is the file copied from windows. Had 2 use dos2unix command to fx it